# can't get gradle to accept java-client-6.0.0-BETA1.jar in android studio 3

Tags: android-studio, appium

I'm new to android studio.  I'm trying to get Android Studio Gradle to build with appium's java-client-6.0.0-BETA1.jar.  I'm implementing appium.  I believe android studio is install right.  I've downloaded the recommended files for appium, selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar, selenium-remote-driver.jar, selenium-java-3.8.1.zip and anything else I can see needed.  Appium server is installed and working.  An android emulator is running and working.

I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Repositories\ApkProjects\EndToEndAndroidTest\app\libs\java-client-6.0.0-BETA1.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:550)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$1(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing io/appium/java_client/touch/TapOptions.class
The dependency contains Java 8 bytecode. Please enable desugaring by adding the following to build.gradle
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
```

I've tried the recommended fix - makes no difference. I've updated guava-23.3-android also which was giving similar errors.

The gradle.build file is:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nwri.endtoendandroidtest"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
//    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.3-android'
}
```

I've searched the web and can't find anyone having this issue. Here is a screen shot if that helps:

[Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G85L.png)

Comment: Why not to use stable release of appium client 5.0.4? Beta mean it might not work :) You don't need to add selenium dependency as it is already in appium client library and your version might conflict if you did not exclude it from appium dependency

Comment: Why do you want to add the dependency as JAR. Add it as Gradle dependency `testCompile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '6.0.0-BETA1'`

Comment: Hey Author were you able to solve the problem?Am getting the same

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Source Compatibility` and `Target Compatibility` to 1.8 in **Project Structure** dialog helped me.

While manual adding

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

did not help.

[image]